# SmartGWT ListGrid field resize

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

My SmartGWT ListGrid have some fields, wich contain long string. I set property `"countryGrid.setCanResizeFields(true)"`.

When I change the width of the field, I want to see something like this: **|A very long dat...|**

Data that does not fit, will be replaced by Dots.
But instead, my string data simply cutted, like this **|A very long dat|**

What property is responsible?

Here is my code:

```
    //deptartment Tab
    deptGrid.setWidth100();
    deptGrid.setHeight(300);
    deptGrid.setTop(50);
    deptGrid.setAlternateRecordStyles(true);
    deptGrid.setShowAllRecords(true);
    deptGrid.setCanRemoveRecords(true);
    deptGrid.setCanEdit(true);

    ListGridField emplIdField_DepTab = new ListGridField("id", "ID", 40);
    ListGridField nameField_DepTab = new ListGridField("name", "NAM", 200);
    ListGridField deptIdField_DepTab = new ListGridField("deptId", "DEPARTMENT");
    ListGridField buildingIdField_DepTab = new ListGridField("buildingId", "BUILDING");

    deptGrid.setFields(new ListGridField[] { 
            emplIdField_DepTab, nameField_DepTab, deptIdField_DepTab, buildingIdField_DepTab 
            });
    deptGrid.setCanResizeFields(false);
    deptGrid.setShowAllRecords(true); 
    deptGrid.setShowRecordComponentsByCell(true);
    deptGrid.setFixedRecordHeights(true);  
    deptGrid.setAutoFetchData(true);
    deptGrid.setAutoFitMaxRecords(3);  
    deptGrid.setAutoFitData(Autofit.VERTICAL);
    deptGrid.setShowFilterEditor(true); 
    deptGrid.setCanEdit(true);
```

Comment: May be you are doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: Just update you post with the code. I'll look into it. What version of SmartGWT and GWT are you using?

Comment: Right now I'am busy. I'll update you after some time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write any code for this functionality. This is the by default behavior of the `ListGrid`.

Please have a look at [Smart GWT Showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_columnsize) with live sample code for more clarity.

---

**EDIT**

The issue may be caused by using older version of Smart GWT. Try it again with latest nightly build of Smart GWT.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I do everything like in example.

Comment: It's fine for as expected without any change in your code. Can you tell me what version of Smart GWT or GWT are you using? I tried with sample data and I can see ellipsis in first column because it's width is only 40 px wide as per your code.

Comment: Great thank! the reason was that I used an older version

Comment: Sounds Good. I'll update it my post then simply close the post if resolved.